# Python - guessing game making sure user don't input same letter twice

Tags: python-2.7

So basically here is what I have;

```
print "***Welcome to Code Breaker***"

print "\n"

rounds = raw_input("How many rounds do you want to play (has to be a positive integer)? ")

while rounds.isdigit() == False or int(rounds) < 1:    
    rounds = raw_input("ERROR:How many turns do you want to play (has to be a positve integer)? ")

print "\n"

i = 0

while i < int(rounds):
    i = i + 1
    for i2 in range(2):
        if i2 == 0:
            player = 1
            breaker = 2
        else:
            player = 2
            breaker = 1

    print "Round" + str(i) + ":***Player " + str(player) + "'s turn to setup the game.***"

    print "Player " + str(breaker) + " look away PLEASE!"

    secret = raw_input("Type in the secret word, QUICKLY? ")

    while secret.isalpha() == False:
        secret = raw_input("ERROR: Type in the secret word (has to be letters): ")

    secret = secret.lower()
    print "\n"*100


    numberOfGuess = raw_input("How many guesses will you allow?(has to be a positive integer) ")

    while numberOfGuess.isdigit() == False or int(numberOfGuess) < 1:
        numberOfGuess = raw_input("ERROR:How many guesses will you allow? (has to be a positive integer) ")

    def maskWord(state, word, guess):
        state = list(state)
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i] == guess:
                state[i] = guess
        return "".join(state)


    word = secret
    state = "*" * len(word)
    tries = 0
    print "Secret Word = " + state
    play = True

    while play:
        if tries == int(numberOfGuess): 
            print "Fail...";
            break
            play = False
        guess = raw_input("Guess a letter (a-z)? ")

        while guess.isalpha() == False or len(guess)!= 1:
            guess = raw_input("ERROR: Guess a letter (a-z)? ")

        guess = guess.lower()
        tries +=1
        state = maskWord(state, word, guess)
        print state
        if maskWord(state, word, guess) == word:  
            print "WIN, WIN!!"; 
            play = False


    print "\n" * 100
```

Question: In guessing section of the code I want to set it up as the user cannot guess the same letter twice. I know you have to use an empty list and use .append function to store the data. However I've tried it and in many different ways it just doesn't seem to work. I have no idea where I'm doing it wrong and if anyone can answer this it would be great. I need to know what it would look like and where I should place it in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typical to use a set to track such things.

```
used_letters = set()  # a new empty set
# ...
if guess in used_letters:  # test presence
  print "This letter has been used already!"
else:
  used_letters.add(guess) # remember as used
```

You can use a `list()` and `.append(guess)` instead. With a list, it's less efficient, but in your case the inefficiency is totally non-detectable.

The point of using a `set` is to convey the idea that duplicate letters are not supposed to exist. (You know, programs are much more often read than written.)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read all the code but looking at your question, I think you are looking for something like that:

```
l = []

#build list

char = 'a'

if char in l:
    print('error')
else:
    l.append(char)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man =) even though I don't understand the char = 'a' part xD

Comment: It's just to have a sample, so in your example it will be the input of the user. ;)